# Binary Search Tree unclear outcome

Tags: c

Trying to learn about Binary Tree while preparing for an exam, and I came across this code. And even tho it looks like it makes sense I simply cannot understand the purpose of this and how it actually works, so can anyone please elaborate?

this is the result I get : https://i.ibb.co/3TTjJBr/kkkkkkkkkkkkj.jpg

```
space += 5;

print_tree(root->right, space);

printf("\n");
for (int i = 5; i < space; i++) {
    printf(" ");
}

printf("%d\n", root->number);

print_tree(root->left, space);
```

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? It can't be both, so please ***edit*** your question to remove the irrelevant tag. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It seems, space describes the printed space between 2 nodes in print_tree(). You should have a look at print_tree();

Comment: Okay, thanks that's what I thought. And what about this part? for (int i = 5; i < space; i++) {
    printf(" ");

Comment: It prints 5 or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have this binary tree

```
            24
          /    \
        18      31
       / \      / \
     11   20  29   33 
    /      \        \
   7       21        55
```

You need to print it with the root on the left and "growing" to the right. So traverse the tree *inorder* (right sub tree, root, left sub tree).

`print_tree` is called recursively, so that the first number printed is the bigger one one (`55`) and its horizontal position is determined by the number of calls (`space += 5`). Note that the loop which prints the spaces starts from 5, so that the root is always printed 5 spaces to the left of its sub trees. It could have been written as

```
print_tree(root->right, space + 5);

putchar('\n');
for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {     
    putchar(' ');
}

printf("%d\n", root->number);  

print_tree(root->left, space + 5);
```